# Error when introducing dummy variables in a regression in Matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-regression, logistic-regression, dummy-data

I am running some regressions in Matlab. My first three regressions are:

```
tbl1=table(Y1,X1); 
mdl1=fitlm(tbl1,'Y1~X1'); 
mdl12=fitglm(tbl1,'Y1~X1','Distribution','binomial','link','probit'); 
mdl13=fitglm(tbl1,'Y1~X1','Distribution','binomial');
```

- Y1 is my dependent variable, it’s binary, it only takes the values 0 or 1.
- X1, the independent variable, is a 1-column logical variable. It is a dummy, it only takes the values of 1 and 0 too.

These 3 different models are working.

I previously built groups of dummies to control for different effects (e.g: year, industry, number of employees, etc) for example:

```
group1=cell2mat(A(:,5));
[~, ~, ugroup1] = unique(group1)
D1=dummyvar(ugroup1);
D1(:,1)=[0];                       %Define reference group
D1=logical(D1);
```

Or

```
group2=cell2mat(A(:,6));
x2 = [0 10 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60 70 100 300];
 [n2, idx2] = histc(group2, x2);
D2 = bsxfun(@eq, idx2, 1:length(x2)-1);
D2(:,1)=[0];
```

In total I have 94 dummies, grouped in 4 different logical arrays (D1-48 levels, D2-13 levels, D3- 6 levels and D4-27 levels).

What I am trying to do now is to add them to the regressions above:

```
tbl1=table(Y1,X1,D1,D2,D3,D4); 
mdl1=fitlm(tbl1,'Y1~X1+D1+D2+D3+D4'); 
mdl12=fitglm(tbl1,'Y1~X1+D1+D2+D3+D4','Distribution','binomial','link','probit'); 
mdl13=fitglm(tbl1,'Y1~X1+D1+D2+D3+D4','Distribution','binomial');
```

But I always get  errors :

> ```
> 1.Error using classreg.regr.FitObject/selectVariables (line 402)
> Predictor variables must be numeric vectors, numeric matrices, or categorical vectors.
>
> 2.Error in classreg.regr.TermsRegression/selectVariables (line 370)
>             model = selectVariables@classreg.regr.ParametricRegression(model);
>
> 3.Error in classreg.regr.FitObject/doFit (line 217)
>             model = selectVariables(model);
> ```

I have been trying different options like changing the type of variable or adding for example`tbl1.D1=nominal(D1);` but it always gives error. I guess it must be related to the way I 'introduce' the dummy groups.

Could someone please help me? Thank you.

I tried this (all variables were changed to doubles):

```
Y=[Y1];
x=[X1 D1 D2 D3 D4];
mdl23=fitglm(x,Y,'Distribution','binomial');
```

It works but I am not sure it is right. I get this warning:

> Warning: Iteration limit reached.

I don't understand why since I reduced a lot my dummy levels.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that all the inputs to `table()` are column vectors. If you give it row vectors, it'll accept them, but then `fitglm()` and `fitglme()` will fail because they expect column vectors.